# ODAC for visual studio 2013

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

There are a lot of ODAC download at the Oracle website but I want to know what is the right ODAC to download for my VS 2013? I have a Windows 7 64-bit OS.

And also, do I need to install ODAC on BOTH my laptop (where I will create my project) and to the Oracle database server?

When I'm trying to connect to my Oracle database, it throws me this error:

```
System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater
```

so I read other blogs saying that I should install ODAC, but these blogs example are using either VS2005 or VS2008, but mine is VS2013

Comment: Which Version has your Oracle Database Serve? Which ODAC did you download? You need ODAC only on the client, not on the database server.

Comment: @miracle173 >> Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Wernfried Domscheit pointed out that solution i referenced are outdated. He is right, I tried from *ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20)* the program `setupt.exe` and it immediately asked me for an admin user. So I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with easy answers:

No, you don't have to install any ODAC on Oracle database server (most likely they might be installed anyway by default)

It does not matter at all which Visual Studio you have, regarding Oracle installation they are all the same.

Now regarding your error:

"Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle", i.e. `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for ages, you should not use it in new projects. You should use the Oracle provider "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" (ODP.NET), so by downloading ODAC from Oracle you have been on the right path.

When you like to use ODP.NET you also have to install an Oracle Client, otherwise it does not work (this requirement is also valid for `System.Data.OracleClient`, that's the actual error you get).

You can either install "Oracle Instant Client" and ODP.NET or download full Oracle Client where you can make a "Custom" installation. There you have to enable component "Oracle Data Provider for .NET" at least.

It is important to have everywhere the same architecture, i.e. Oracle Client, ODP.NET and your application must be all the same - either x86 or x64 ("AnyCPU" means x64 on nowadays 64-bit Windows). In case you have to support both x86 and x64 follow [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100) to install x86 and x64 on one machine.

Another possibility is to use the "ODP.NET Managed Driver", this one is just a single .dll and does not require any further Oracle client installation. Unlike "ODP.NET" the "ODP.NET Managed Driver" does not depend on the architecture, i.e. it works for both x86 and x64.

It does not matter whether your database is 32-bit or 64-bit. This applies for everything mentioned above.